# Liquid templates: strange behavior when assigning variables within for loops

Tags: template-engine, liquid

I'm learning Liquid (using [grunt-liquid](https://github.com/sirlantis/grunt-liquid)). I've run into some extremely strange behavior with a simple `for` loop. Perhaps you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is version 1 of my code, which works as expected:

```
{% assign isThree = 'initial value' %}

{% for i in (1..9) %}

    {% if i == 3 %}
        {% assign isThree = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign isThree = false %}
    {% endif %}

    <p>{{ i }}: {{ isThree }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Basically, it loops through the numbers 1 through 9, and displays each one, along with a boolean indicating whether or not the number is three. This produces the expected output:

```
1: false
2: false
3: true
4: false
5: false
6: false
7: false
8: false
9: false
```

And here's version 2 of my code, which exhibits the strange behavior in question. It's identical to version 1, except it now assigns a variable named `someOtherVar` before assigning `isThree`:

```
{% assign isThree = 'initial value' %}

{% for i in (1..9) %}

    {% assign someOtherVar = 'foo' %}

    {% if i == 3 %}
        {% assign isThree = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign isThree = false %}
    {% endif %}

    <p>{{ i }}: {{ isThree }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

This change shouldn't affect the output at all, but it does! In effect, it makes it so that values assigned to `isThree` aren't available until the *next* iteration of the loop:

```
1: initial value
2: false
3: false
4: true
5: false
6: false
7: false
8: false
9: false
```

If I move the `someOtherVar` assignment *below* the `{% if %}` block, then everything works fine again.

What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Looks like a bug in [liquid-node](https://github.com/sirlantis/liquid-node), or possibly in grunt-liquid.

Comment: It certainly seems that way, although it'd be a pretty blatant bug. I opened an issue on GitHub. Thanks.